# How to Avoid throwing 400 errors from ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, express, cookies, session-cookies, http-status-code-400

**Background:** I am getting 400 errors (and a blank 400 page response) from a malformed cookie on my site (coming from one of my affiliate pages). I have wrote a code to delete the cookie, but some of my customers still get an error because it's in their cache. Once they clear their cache the problem is fixed.

This issue is circumvented all together in my .NET code base by simply ignoring a 400 error, I would like to do the same in Express JS.

**Ask:** I would like to have express ignore all cookies on a 400 error (often caused by defective cookies) or to at least ignore the error all together. Is there any way to do this?

**My ClearDefectiveCookies function for reference (functioning correctly)**

```
const clearDefectiveCookies = (req, res, next) => {
  const cookies = req.cookies;
  const defectiveCookies = Object.keys(cookies).filter(key => typeof cookies[key] === 'string' && (cookies[key].charAt(0) === '='));

  if (defectiveCookies.length > 0) {
    defectiveCookies.forEach(defectiveCookie => {
      res.clearCookie(defectiveCookie);
    });
  }

  next();
};
```

**Problematic Cookie for Reference**

Name: `xyz_123` and value: `=NaN=xyz=123`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is actually that node had a breaking change in November 2018, it isn't the cookie that is the issue, it's that node has a max cookie size causing the 400 errors. It isn't actually express..

See answer here: [Why am I getting 400 errors? Node, Express, ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56011525/why-am-i-getting-400-errors-node-express-reactjs/56011526#56011526)

Answer (score 4):

Possibly that the problem is the way how you call `res.clearCookie`. If you look in the [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.clearCookie), it says:

> Web browsers and other compliant clients will only clear the cookie if the given options is identical to those given to `res.cookie()`, excluding expires and maxAge.

So in order to clear the cookies, you will have to provide a second argument as an object, providing the path.

Comment: Hey Shimon, thx for the response. It does work properly and correctly gets rid of the cookie. But it seems that the middleware might do it to late before the 400 error is thrown. Not sure how to get it to ignore the 400 errors all together, because my code successfully deletes the broken cookies